# How to query DateTimeOffset in Cosmos?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following data where I want to query against `itemUpdateDateTime`.

```
[
    {
        "itemUpdateDateTime": "2024-08-13T22:34:35.9988856+00:00",
        "location": "A",
        "type": "Sedan"
    },
    {
        "itemUpdateDateTime": "2024-02-22T22:08:07.7576464+00:00",
        "location": "B",
        "type": "SUV"
    }
]
```

I want to get records by using `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=` against `itemUpdateDateTime`.

Meaning,

- When I say `SELECT c.location WHERE c.itemUpdateDateTime <= '2024-08-13'` then I should see `"location": "A"`
- When I say `SELECT c.location WHERE c.itemUpdateDateTime < '2024-08-13'` then I should NOT see `"location": "A"` and so on.

How to query against offset when you just have date as `2024-08-13` format?

Comment: Is the `year` saved in first item is correct? according to your requirement given in the question i.e.

Show this record on `<=`
Do not show this record on `<` or `>=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude **`T22:34:35.9988856+00:00`** to get the required output by using the **`SUBSTRING`** function in the query, as shown below:

```sql
SELECT c.location FROM c WHERE SUBSTRING(c.itemUpdateDateTime, 0, 10) <= '2024-08-13'
```

The above query uses `SUBSTRING` to include only the `date` from `itemUpdateDateTime` and also uses `<=` to retrieve the output.

**Output:**

```js
[
    {
        "location": "A"
    },
    {
        "location": "B"
    }
]
```

Comment: here this is not fulfilling my 2nd condition where if I have `<` then it should just give me `location=B`.

Comment: Found the solution.